# In EntityFramework after insert to db, DBset returns same value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The problem is DbSet returns same value all time but database changes.

Here is a sample code (I used Repository Pattern and Database First Approach and MVC). After insert or delete method, Database saves changes but in View I can't see result.

The code below is a part of my project. There are rooms and lectures and roomlectures table in db. and it adds selected roomlecture to table.

you can check it on [Github](https://github.com/ncdlek/MusicSchool)

**BaseRepository.cs**

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected MusicSchoolContext db;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> table;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        db = new MusicSchoolContext();
        table = db.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public int Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        table.Add(entity);
        return Save();
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Detail(int? id)
        {
            if (!id.HasValue)
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            Room room = DataService.Service.roomService.SelectOne(x => x.Id == id);
        }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrRemoveLecture(RoomLecture rl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            rl.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;

            RoomLecture item = DataService.Service.roomLectureService
                .SelectOne(x => x.LectureId == rl.LectureId && x.RoomId == rl.RoomId);

            if (item != null)
                DataService.Service.roomLectureService.Delete(item.Id);
            else
                DataService.Service.roomLectureService.Insert(rl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = rl.RoomId });
    }
```

Comment: The code seems correct, can't seem to pinpoint any mistakes. 

Is room variable being populated correctly with the proper entity ?
Ideally you should use the debugger to see exactly where it is failing. Also, may be dumb, but, confirm that the View value is not statically written

Comment: @MarkCutajar No, after stop debugging and relaunch, view is running correctly.

Comment: Does the `Save()` method call `SaveChanges()` method of the `MusicSchoolContext`, in your code it is called `db`?

Comment: Could you provide proper links for your files?

Comment: @SayusiAndo i added github link

Comment: Could you give links to the files, to BaseRepository and to the given Controller?

Comment: @SayusiAndo BaseRepository: https://github.com/ncdlek/MusicSchool/blob/master/MS.BLL/Repository/BaseRepository.cs RoomController: https://github.com/ncdlek/MusicSchool/blob/master/MS.UI/Controllers/RoomController.cs

Comment: Are you sure you are writing and reading the same database? Are you sure there is no some seed method somewhere? Have you debugged it? I checked your files, they seems fine. the bug must be somewhere super trivial place in your code.

Comment: @SayusiAndo after stop debugging and relaunch it runs perfectly. it just doesn't get updates

Comment: What does it means it does not get updates? You cannot add new data, or you cannot update a given entity?

Comment: @SayusiAndo it adds entity to database. but dataset returns first values. without last inserted one

Comment: I haven't looked through your github, but is it maybe possible that you have a static `DbContext` instance instead of creating a new `DbContext` for each request? (To me it sounds like the problem might be related to the caching of entities done by the `DbContext`)

Comment: @bassfader Maybe, but i am using repository pattern and using same dbcondext for all controllers but only this doesn't work. I am missing something but I don't get it :(